# Is there a timeout on warp server response?

Tags: haskell, haskell-warp

I have a web application using warp and while trying to query some large-ish using curl I noticed the connection get shutdown exactly after 1 minute transfer. I increased curl's own timeout but this did not changed anything so I assume this is set on the server side.

Is this actually the case there is a 60s timeout on sending response in warp, and if yes, how can I control it?

Comment: Try setting the timeout in the 'Settings' (see http://hackage.haskell.org/package/warp-3.0.13.1/docs/Network-Wai-Handler-Warp.html#v:setTimeout). Though it says the default is 30s in the documentation so it's probably not the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Looks like it's what I am looking for... Not sure how to set these options in scotty though.